Why is foil shield more efficient than a braid for high frequency noise?
I found that for high frequency noise, a foil shield is better than braid. What physically happens to high frequency noise in a foil that makes it more efficient than a braid?

Found -- how? Please describe your setup so that we can assess it. What type of braid did you compare with? They are not all created equally.

Usually the difference simply is that the foil covers 100% of the shielded inner wires while a braid only covers 70% to 95% of the inner wires.
So as an analogue, foil shield is an unbroken metal tube and braid is a metal tube with holes.

yes, but what the hight frequence is related to the 30% uncovered of the braid?

Higher frequencies have a shorter wavelength than low frequencies.  Which helps them to fit through small gaps.

I think the best is a combination though, because I wouldn't necessarily trust  foil to stay unbroken after careless handling and you wouldn't know from just looking, and it would still work.

For simplicity, you can think of the braid as a foil but with apertures/openings/holes/slits. The size of these determines which frequency components will propagate freely or trapped or suppressed, just like a filter.
The EM waves have wavelength (λ) and frequency (f). The relation is
$$
c = \lambda f
$$
where \$c\$ is the speed of light in the environment (air or vacuum or what/wherever).
As the frequency increases the wavelength gets smaller. The smaller the aperture, the more difficult for high frequencies to "pass through".

Thank you! I got it regarding the high frequences, but phisically what makes the braid be more efficient in low frequences? as the low frequence has larger wave length, how does it behave in the braid? is this more efficient because the braid has a larger content of copper?

@BrunoPimenta Yes, at low frequencies, the braid has more cross-section, it's thicker, and thus skin effect dominates to lower frequencies than for foil.

@Tim Williams, Didn't understand your comment

The braid has small apertures, through which photons may pass, but those photons must have a wavelength smaller than the aperture itself, in the same way that the small holes in a microwave oven's door shield are smaller than the wavelength of the microwaves inside, preventing them from escaping. Why this works is a question for the physicists.
Let's say the largest "gap" in a braid shield is \$1\rm{\ mm} = 1\times 10^{-3}\rm{\ m}\$, then the corresponding frequency of EM radiation would be:
$$ f = \frac{c}{\lambda} = \frac{3\times10^8\rm{\ ms^{-1}}}{1\times 10^{-3}\rm{\ m}} = 300\rm{\ GHz} $$
Photons of frequency greater than that can be transmitted through the braid. Lower frequency photons are blocked, and their energy will result in current in the shield rather than the inner conductor. The "cut-off" isn't sharp though; some longer wavelength photons may still traverse, but it becomes less likely with increasing wavelength.
300GHz is the upper bound of the microwave spectrum. I don't know what background electromagnetic radiation beyond that is present in a typical environment, but it would have a better chance of defeating a braid, than a foil shield.
Lower frequency EM radiation that is absorbed by the shield will result in current in that conductor, just like an antenna. This will develop a potential difference between the ends, which would appear as noise from the perspective of the receiver. The shield's resistance is deliberately kept low, to mitigate this. If the foil conductor has lower end-to-end resistance than the braid, it will develop a smaller potential difference. Also, inductance of the shield conductor will influence that potential difference; a higher inductance braid would produce larger voltages at all frequencies.
If you are able to measure that noise, it would suggest that you are dealing with megahertz, rather than gigahertz, most of which is likely environmental noise coupled into your own circuit before or after the cable, or even produced by the circuit itself. I suspect the reason that this noise is attenuated differently by different types of shield has more to do with capacitance between the cable conductors, and inductance of the shield itself, than photons finding their way through holes.
The smaller surface area of a braid would have lower capacitance than foil, which in combination with any impedances at either end of the inner conductor (carrying the signal) would produce a higher cut-off frequency. A foil shield will begin attenuating at a lower frequency, so you'll see less noise (and signal) power at higher frequencies.

Regarding words like "pass" and "block", readers may find the top half of: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/721600/311631 useful context. (The same point is hinted at here by "less likely with increasing wavelength".)

I'm not sure what the last paragraph is saying -- could you explain this better, and add what assumptions are being used? I'm not imagining in what way a braid has lower "surface area" or capacitance; keep in mind impedance and velocity is dominated by cross-sectional geometry and dielectric, regardless of foil, braid, or tube (e.g. rigid line).

@TimWilliams I am referring to capacitance between shield and inner conductor. I envisage the shield as a plate, having holes drilled into it. I assumed that the solid plate would have higher capacitance with the inner conductor than the plate with holes. That is based purely on intuition, having not performed any rigourous verification.

Ah, okay.  FYI, the electric field that leaks out, is extremely small -- consider a vacuum tube geometry, if you're familiar: the grid wire diameter and spacing can leave quite a lot of visible cross-section, say more than 50%; yet the mu factor (essentially the electric field shielding factor) can still be 20, 40. Conversely, the amount of capacitance lost compared to a solid plate/sheet is 1 - 1/mu, or still very close to 1. Braid would have to be very loose (and leaky!) indeed to have a noticeable effect on C; but the dielectric can simply be adjusted to compensate and maintain Zo.
